# Does adding a remote repo affect whether my commits show in my github contribution history?

Tags: git, github

My workflow has been as follows:

```
$ git checkout -b [name_of_new_branch]
```

[work on feature]

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "my message"
$ git remote add [name_of_new_remote] [url of github repo]
$ git push origin [name_of_remote] [name_of_branch]
```

These commits were showing up in my github contribution history. I then switched to a slightly different workflow:

```
$ git checkout -b [name_of_new_branch]
```

[work on feature]

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "my message"
$ git push origin
```

It now seems like new commits are not showing up in my contribution history. At least I think that's what is causing the difference. Why is the remote making a difference?

Comment: Maybe `origin` is a different remote than `[name_of_remote]`. What is the output of `git remote -v`? (That will show you what remote name is associated with what URLs.)

Comment: Only `master` (or default git branch) and `gh-pages` are counted for contributions. See the [docs](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/) for more info.

Comment: @bagage So when I add the [url of github repo], that is actually a gh-page? I was just using https://github.com/[other_user]/[project]. The pushed branch is still showing at https://github.com/[other_user]/[project]/tree/[name of branch]

Comment: I am voting to close this question as off topic

Answer (score 0):

I still have my contribution history shown on github when working on other machines with different branches. Can you double check if you have the email set up correctly? The email for that git should be link to your github account.

Comment: Email should not be the problem, I have used the same email and it is linked with my account.

Comment: Can you do a ```git remote -v``` I think the second time when you checkout -b to a new branch, the remote might not be the same as previous...

Comment: I see a fetch and push url. Both match the url I would previously be giving `$ git remote add [name_of_new_remote] [url]`